# Android - How do I remember if a button was clicked?

Tags: java, android, if-statement, button, textview

I am building a calculator that uses two textViews as inputs and one textView as a Results box. When I press the +, -, x, or / buttons the program will switch to textView2 and continue entering numbers. Then the = button will be clicked to perform the calculation.

When I click the = button the program forgets that I pressed the +, -, x, or / buttons so it won't know how it should calculate.

**Is there a way I can "remember" the first button click so I can use it to determine what to calculate?**

> Android Code **UPDATED, V2**

```
    package com.example.tristan.assn2;

import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.TextView;


public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    TextView operand1, operand2,result,tv;
    int operation;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        operand1 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView);
        operand2 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView2);

        result= (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView3);
        tv=operand1;
    }

    public void sendMessage(View v) {
        if (v.getId() == R.id.button18 || v.getId() == R.id.button15 || v.getId() == R.id.button17 || v.getId() == R.id.button21 || v.getId() == R.id.button18) {
            tv=operand2;
        }

        if (v.getId() == R.id.button) {
            tv.setText(tv.getText() + "1");
        }
        if (v.getId() == R.id.button2) {
            tv.setText(tv.getText() + "2");
        }
        if (v.getId() == R.id.button3) {
            tv.setText(tv.getText() + "3");
        }
        if (v.getId() == R.id.button4) {
            tv.setText(tv.getText() + "4");
        }
        if (v.getId() == R.id.button5) {
            tv.setText(tv.getText() + "5");
        }
        if (v.getId() == R.id.button6) {
            tv.setText(tv.getText() + "6");
        }
        if (v.getId() == R.id.button7) {
            tv.setText(tv.getText() + "7");
        }
        if (v.getId() == R.id.button8) {
            tv.setText(tv.getText() + "8");
        }
        if (v.getId() == R.id.button9) {
            tv.setText(tv.getText() + "9");
        }
        if (v.getId() == R.id.button10) {
            tv.setText(tv.getText() + "0");
        }
        if (v.getId() == R.id.button11) {
            tv.setText(tv.getText() + ".");
        }




        Button plus =  (Button) findViewById(R.id.button17);
        Button minus =  (Button) findViewById(R.id.button15);
        Button mult =  (Button) findViewById(R.id.button18);
        Button div =  (Button) findViewById(R.id.button21);

            //plus
        if(v.getId()==R.id.button17){
            operation = 1;
        }
        //minus
        if(v.getId()==R.id.button15){
            operation = 2;
        }
        //mult
        if(v.getId()==R.id.button18){
            operation = 3;
        }
        //div
        if(v.getId()==R.id.button21){
            operation = 4;
        }


        int op1, op2;
        switch(operation){
            case 1:
                op1=Integer.parseInt(operand1.getText().toString());
                op2=Integer.parseInt(operand2.getText().toString());
                op2+=op1;
                if(v.getId()==R.id.button23){
                    result.setText(op2+"");
                    tv=operand1;
                }
                break;
            case 2:
                op1=Integer.parseInt(operand1.getText().toString());
                op2=Integer.parseInt(operand2.getText().toString());
                op2-=op1;
                if(v.getId()==R.id.button23){
                    result.setText(op2+"");
                    tv=operand1;
                }
                break;
            case 3:
                op1=Integer.parseInt(operand1.getText().toString());
                op2=Integer.parseInt(operand2.getText().toString());
                op2*=op1;
                if(v.getId()==R.id.button23){
                    result.setText(op2+"");
                    tv=operand1;
                }
                break;
            case 4:
                op1=Integer.parseInt(operand1.getText().toString());
                op2=Integer.parseInt(operand2.getText().toString());
                op2/=op1;
                if(v.getId()==R.id.button23){
                    result.setText(op2+"");
                    tv=operand1;
                }
                break;
        }

    }
}
```

> How do I assign the operations?

```
    //plus
    if(v.getId()==R.id.button17){
        operation = 1;
    }
    //minus
    if(v.getId()==R.id.button15){
        operation = 2;
    }
    //mult
    if(v.getId()==R.id.button18){
        operation = 3;
    }
    //div
    if(v.getId()==R.id.button21){
        operation = 4;
    }
```

Comment: need to store that in the properties...

Comment: Seems to me like each button press adds and item to a list.. then the equals button evaluates the list, in order. Really, you can evaluate the stack at any point. You just need to have somewhere that is maintained.

Comment: just remember with some booleans?

Comment: It seems to me that this is what variables are for.

Answer (score 0):

```
private String operation;
```

In the output of each operation, you write:
For the plus:

```
operation = "+";
```

For minus:

```
operation = "-";
```

For div:

```
operation = "/";
```

and so on...
For checked, query the variable **operation**.
switch or if.

```
switch (operation) { 
    case "+": 
        //Your operation 
        break; 
    case "-": 
        //Your operation  
        break;
    case "/": 
        //Your operation  
        break;
}
```

Comment: Thank you. I updated the code above. Am doing this correctly? When I try and run the code, my app crashes.

Comment: Hi friend, Show me please, where application crashed? in log you can see this information?

Answer (score 0):

You should create a variable somewhere in your `Activity` that stores a representation of the button (plus, minus, etc..) that was pressed.  This could simply be a string value that says "plus", "minus", etc. Then implement an `OnClickListener` for each operator button, setting the variable appropriately.  Then you can just check this variable to see what operation was performed.

Also, instead of having four separate `if` statements beginning with `v.getId() == R.id.button23`, you can combine them into one `if` statement and only change how you compute `op2` based on the value of the operator variable.

Comment: Is there a good resource I can find on how to do that? Can you give an example on how to set up the listener for "plus"?

Comment: @Tristan check this out: http://blog.cubeactive.com/onclicklistener-android-tutorial/

Answer (score 0):

I would use a stack for this. When you tap on 1, for example, add that to the stack. When you tap on + add that to the stack. When you take on 3, add that to the stack. You can then pop each item off the state and whatever the operator is, you can perform that function.....

You can determine what each item is when you pop it off the stack. if #, store in var1, if +, -, /, *, do something else.... doing it that way will allow you to keep track of EVERYTHING on a stack.

One thing to keep it mind, if you put 8, 3, 1 on a stack, in that order, when you pop them, it'll be 1, 3, 8.